# HOWTO: Pass different types of objects as a parameter to a method depending on the use case scenario

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, async-await

I am trying to not duplicate code so I have created a parametrized CreateFile method.
One of its parameters, myParams, sometimes can be of type CustomObject_A and other times it can be of type CustomObject_B. So how can I achieve this?

Below the code:

```
public class CustomObject_A {
    public DataTable dt { get; set; }
    public string prop1 { get; set; }
}

public class CustomObject_B {
    public List<AnotherCustomObject> lst { get; set; }
    public int prop2 { get; set; }
}

public void DoWork_CreateFile_A(string baseUrl)
{
        string requestUri = "api/MyController/CreateFile_A";
        CustomObject_A myParams = new CustomObject_A();

        this.CreateFile(baseUrl, requestUri, myParams);
}

public void DoWork_CreateFile_B(string baseUrl)
{
        string requestUri = "api/MyController/CreateFile_B";
        CustomObject_B myParams = new CustomObject_B();

        this.CreateFile(baseUrl, requestUri, myParams);
}

public async Task CreateFile(string strBaseUrl, string requestUri, someType myParams)
{        
     using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
     {
          client.BaseAddress = new Uri(strBaseUrl);
          client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();
          client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

          string stringMyParams = await Task.Run(() => JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myParams, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented,JsonSerializerSettings { ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver() }));

          var httpContent = new StringContent(stringMyParams, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
          HttpResponseMessage res = await client.PostAsync(requestUri, httpContent);

          if (res.IsSuccessStatusCode)
          {
              // Do things
          }
     }
}
```

Web API Controller:

```
public class MyController : ApiController
{
        public bool CreateFile_A(string data)
        {
              CustomObject_A myData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CustomObject_A>(data);
              // Do some stuff here
        }

        public bool CreateFile_B(string data)
        {
             CustomObject_B myData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CustomObject_B>(data);
             // Do some stuff here
        }
}
```

Comment: Since you do not use any type specific member of `myParams` in `CreateFile` you can simply use `object` as a type for `myParams`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are multiple ways to achieve it, depends on what you want to accomplish..

1. **Generic method**

   ```
   public async Task CreateFile<T>(string strBaseUrl, string requestUri, T myParams)
    { 
       ....
    }
   ```
2. **Interface**

   ```
    public void DoSomething<T>(T param) where T: IFileCreator
    {
       param.CreateFile();
    }

    public interface IFileCreator
    {
        void CreateFile();  
    }

    public abstract class FileCreatorBase : IFileCreator
    {
        public virtual void CreateFile()
        {
           //common code
        }
    }

    public class ClassA : FileCreatorBase
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public override void CreateFile()
        {
            Id.Dump();
        }
    }

    public class ClassB : FileCreatorBase
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }    

        public override void CreateFile()
        {
           Name.Dump();
        }
    }
   ```
3. **Abstract Class w/virtual method**

   ```
        public abstract class FileCreator
        {
            public virtual void CreateFile()
            {
                //common code
            }
        }

        public class ClassA : FileCreator
        {
           public int Id { get; set; }

           public override void CreateFile()
           {
              Id.Dump();
           }
        }

        public class ClassB : FileCreator
        {
            public string Name { get; set; }

            public override void CreateFile()
            {
                Name.Dump();
            }
        }
   ```
4. **Abstract Class w/ abstract method**

   ```
    public abstract class FileCreator
    {
        public abstract void CreateFile();  
    }

    public class ClassA : FileCreator
    {
       public int Id { get; set; }

       public override void CreateFile()
       {
          Id.Dump();
       }
    }

    public class ClassB : FileCreator
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public override void CreateFile()
        {
            Name.Dump();
        }
    }
   ```

Comment: answer looks good to me, but I'm starting to wonder if this is a homework question.

Answer (score 1):

All your similar classes need to inherit from a common interface, and then you can use the interface as the type that the methods take.  Anything that inherits that interface can be passed in.

Comment: I think an interface is not working here because of CustomObject_A and CustomObject_B  do not have the same objects with the same type.