# How to receive two different objects in the same API method?

Tags: c#, .net, generics, webhooks

I have an API **.NET 7** that implement a POST method.
This POST will work as a Webhook that can receive two different request body.  As I don't have control of the request, I can't specify a concrete class as parameter of the method.

**My controller:**

```cs
//Receive a generic object 
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Post (object request)
{
  try{
      //should identity the object type, convert to concrete class and call the service
      return Ok();
  }
  catch(Exception ex)
  {
      return BadRequest(ex);
  }
}
```

The possible request bodies it's already defined as a data model:

```
public partial class SignupMatch
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTimeOffset DateCreated { get; set; }
    public DateTimeOffset LastUpdated { get; set; }
    public Match[] Matches { get; set; }
}
```

**And:**

```
public class Proposal
{
    public string mother { get; set; }
    public string gender { get; set; }
    public string nationality { get; set; }
    public string hometownState { get; set; }
    public string hometown { get; set; }
    public string education { get; set; }
    public string relationshipStatus { get; set; }
    public string phoneLandline { get; set; }
}
```

How can I identify which object I am receiving upon request?

Comment: You could try creating a composite class with SignupMatch and Proposal objects as members. And check if either is null.

Comment: Is it always one type at a time? I.e., `request` is always a `SignupMatch` OR a `Proposal`, never AND?

Comment: yes, always a SignupMatch OR a Proposal.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [HOWTO: Pass different types of objects as a parameter to a method depending on the use case scenario](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65114817/howto-pass-different-types-of-objects-as-a-parameter-to-a-method-depending-on-t)

Comment: You mentioned that there is a webhook involved. Cannot you just have two POST actions with different routes and have one action per webhook? If not, could you also specify what will be the payload formats? E.g. if it's both json or if there are also different formats for the distinct requests you get.

Comment: @ZdeněkJelínek, unfortunately not. is only one URL to both and request has same format (json);

Comment: Ok, one last thing: Do you use the out of the box Sytem.Text.Json (STJ) serializer or Newtonsoft.Json (NSJ)? The latter needs to be explicitly configured in ASP.NET Core so if there's no NSJ registration anywhere, it's STJ. This is important as the serializers generally don't support what you need out of the box and we will have to make them do :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like this?

In your program/startup.cs file try adding

```
app.MapControllerRoute(name: "SignupMatch",
                pattern: "SignupMatch",
                defaults: new { controller = "<whatever your controller name is>", action = "SignupMatch" });
app.MapControllerRoute(name: "Proposal",
                pattern: "Proposal",
                defaults: new { controller = "<whatever your controller name is>", action = "Proposal" });
```

Your controller may look something like this

```
public class PostApiController : ControllerBase
{
    public IActionResult SignupMatch(SignupMatch data)
    {
        [Do what you need to do with the data]
    }
    public IActionResult Proposal(Proposal data)
    {
        [Do what you need to do with the data]
    }
}
```

Idea taken from [Routing to controller actions in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-7.0)

Comment: can you explain how it work? never see this approach

Comment: @Guilhermesilva This describes how incoming requests are matched to your specific actions. You have a URL /SignUpMatch; when your API receives a request matching the pattern, it will route your request to the SignUpMatch action.

Comment: This don't work for me. I need a unique url

Comment: One last comment: I apologize for wasting your time if this doesn't work. Your unique URL is your action (e.g., http://localhost/[app_name]/SignUpMatch)

Answer (score 0):

A bit of a hack, but if you really cannot map to separate handlers, then you could get the raw request body as a string, for example:

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpRequest request;

if ( request.Body is not null )
{

   if ( !request.Body.CanSeek )
   {

      request.EnableBuffering();

   }

   try
   {

      request.Body.Position = 0;

      stream_reader = new StreamReader( request.Body, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8 );

      body_str = await stream_reader.ReadToEndAsync();

      // Reset the streams Body position back to 0 after the read ...

      request.Body.Position = 0;

      // Inspect body_str to determine data type ...


   }
   catch ( Exception ex )
   {

      // Log exception ...

   }

}
```

Once you have the request body as a string, you could examine the string to determine which object you are dealing with.  For example, if the request is a JSON string, you could inspect the string for specific properties to determine the object type.  If the request is x-www-form-urlencoded data, then again, you could determine the key/value pairs that are present and determine which object type you are dealing with.

Again, just an idea.

Comment: I think that is a better solution, but I did it in a different way and more simple. I try convert the object using json.Deserialize method to both class, after I'll find specific properties.